# Persisting Lazy Loaded Properties

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-loading

I am using a simple repository pattern and have objects with a LazyList such as:

```
public class Promotion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public LazyList<Site> TargetSites { get; internal set; } // implemented as a LazyList
}
```

This works great for getting the items but I'm wondering what is usual to do for saving the items?

To persist a promotion I then need to save the list of TargetSites only if they were loaded in the first place. Is this the usual pattern with lazy loaded items? I can find lots of info on lazy loading but very little on persisting the resulting modifications to the lazy loaded objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the relationship exists in your data model a call to context.SubmitChanges should save the parent object as well as the child objects if they are loaded and have changed.  That's the beauty of L2S (and other orms).